# How can I center and change the sizes of these items?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, and I'm trying to do an easy challenge from Frontend Mentor. I'm currently stuck with trying to position the card in the center, as well as changing the size of the image and the `div` (although mostly just the image). I have not been able to change it for some reason.

Here's what the desktop layout needs to look like:
[image]

And here's what I have:
[image]

Here's all the CSS I've managed to do so far:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap');

:root {
    /* Primary */
    --veryDarkBlue: hsl(233, 47%, 7%); /* background */
    --darkDesaturatedBlue: hsl(244, 38%, 16%); /* card */
    --softViolet: hsl(277, 64%, 61%); /* accent */

    /* Neutral */
    --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%); /* main heading, stats */
    --SlightlyWhite: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75); /* main paragraph */
    --SlightyWhite2: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6); /* stat headings */
}

* {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--veryDarkBlue);
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.info {
    background-color: var(--darkDesaturatedBlue);
    text-align: center;
}

.image {

}

h1, h2 {
    color: var(--White);
}

.stat-head, p {
    color: var(--SlightyWhite2);
}

.stat-head {
    letter-spacing: .1em;
}

span {
    color: var(--softViolet);
}

@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    .card {
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }

    .info {
        border-top-left-radius: .5em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: .5em;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .image {
        border-top-right-radius: .5em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: .5em;        
    }

    .stats {
        display: inline-flex;
    }
}
```

Edit: Not sure if this should be included, but here's the HTML:

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="image2">
    <img src="/FrontendMentorChallenges/StatsPreviewCard/images/image-header-mobile.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="info">
    <h1>Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow</h1>

    <p>Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency</p>

    <div class="stats">
      <div>
        <h2>10K+</h2>
        <p class="stat-head">COMPANIES</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h2>314</h2>
        <p class="stat-head">TEMPLATES</p>
      </div>
  
      <div>
        <h2>12M+</h2>
        <p class="stat-head">QUERIES</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to set `height: 100%` in your `.card`, `.image2` and `.info` classes, I suggest to try `flex wrap`

Answer (score 0):

So far I have looked up to your code and worked on it however I did not have too much time but it seems this could help you to improve your code.

```html
 <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
        <img
          src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/closed-cardboard-box-taped-isolated-260nw-273611708.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>

      <div class="info">
        <h1>Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow</h1>

        <p>
          Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions
          regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency
        </p>

        <div class="stats">
          <div>
            <h2>10K+</h2>
            <p class="stat-head">COMPANIES</p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2>314</h2>
            <p class="stat-head">TEMPLATES</p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2>12M+</h2>
            <p class="stat-head">QUERIES</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap");

:root {
  /* Primary */
  --veryDarkBlue: hsl(233, 47%, 7%); /* background */
  --darkDesaturatedBlue: hsl(244, 38%, 16%); /* card */
  --softViolet: hsl(277, 64%, 61%); /* accent */

  /* Neutral */
  --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%); /* main heading, stats */
  --SlightlyWhite: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75); /* main paragraph */
  --SlightyWhite2: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6); /* stat headings */
}

* {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--veryDarkBlue);
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 60%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.info {
  background-color: var(--darkDesaturatedBlue);
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -34%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
  color: var(--White);
  padding: 20px;
}
h2 {
  color: var(--White);
}

.info {
  color: var(--SlightyWhite2);
}

.info p {
  padding: 30px;
}

.stat-head p {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.stats p {
  padding: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

span {
  color: var(--softViolet);
}

.stats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  .info {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.5em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .image {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
  }

  .stats {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.